# accepts_nested_attributes_for - Preventing destroy on primary model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, nested-attributes

I have a photo gallery that has a Gallery model and an Asset model. See below:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gallery_name, :description, :assets_attributes 
  has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true

  def find_featured_image
    assets.featured
  end

  def find_only_featured
   assets.only_featured
  end


class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery

  has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => {
      :thumb => '150x150#',
      :medium => '300x300>',
      :large => '600x600>'
    }

  def self.featured
    where( :featured => true ).limit(1)
  end

  scope :only_featured, where(:featured => true)

end
end
```

I am able to destroy the assets through my Gallery form, but when I try to destroy the Gallery itself, I am simply redirected to the Show view with no confirmation notice.

Here is my form:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="headers"><h1>MDN Photo Gallery</h1></div></br>

    <% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>

    <div id="gallery_wrap">
        <div id="gallery_left">
            <div id="gallery_head"><h2><%= gallery.gallery_name %></h2></div>
            <div id="gallery_desc"><%= gallery.description %></div>
        </div>
        <div id="gallery_rt">
            <div id="gallery_featured">
                <% for asset in gallery.assets.featured %>
                  <%= link_to( image_tag(asset.image.url(:medium)), asset.image.url(:large), :class => "fancybox", :rel => gallery.id ) %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div id="gallery_photos">   
            <% for asset in gallery.assets %>   
              <%= link_to( image_tag(asset.image.url(:thumb)), asset.image.url(:large), :class => "fancybox", :rel => gallery.id ) %>
            <% end %>   
            </div>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', gallery %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_gallery_path(gallery) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', gallery, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
        </div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <% end %>
    <br />
<%= link_to 'New Gallery', new_gallery_path %>
</div>
```

I'm using the standard destroy method that gets created with scaffold:

```
def destroy
@gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
@gallery.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(galleries_url) }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
```

Is there some change I need to make to the model? the destroy method? anything else? in order to be able to delete the parent of the nested model?

Thanks in advance for your insights.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds there's something wrong with how the JavaScript support is being loaded. There's no way to have an anchor make a DELETE request directly, so Rails uses JavaScript to respond to the link's click event, and then make the proper request. Without that, the link simply acts as a GET.

Comment: Do you happen to know which .js library in rails is responsible for this? Perhaps the loading order of javascripts has something to do with this.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? If prior to 3.1, have you installed jQuery support, or are you using the default Prototype support?

Comment: I'm using v3.0.3. I am not familiar with the need to install JQuery support. I added JQuery to the default Prototype support. Do you have a link you can refer me to? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion on another site that describes exactly the situation I'm faced with:

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=38460

The recommendation was made to use the button_to instead of the standard link_to for purposes of security against web bots. I had not heard that before.

Also it was observed that the absence of the <%= csrf_meta_tag %> was found and that the original issue went away and the link_to worked. That is not the case for me.

So now I have a button_for and am able to destroy the record. However, I am not getting the confirmation notice (:confirm). So there is still something wrong, but I can at least deal with the need to delete the record.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to get the confirmation notification working (:confirm). What I had done was changed javascript_include_tag :defaults to javascript_include_tag :all. I had forgotten I made that change. I'm not sure what is included when the :defaults method is called, but just wanted to let anyone else running into this problem know that is how I fixed it. Sounds like using the Button_to instead of Link_to is still the best solution even though link_to will work now.